# Sorting out words that have letters in the wrong spot

Tags: python, sorting

So, I'm looking to sort out words that have letters in the wrong spot,
I think I need a way to represent a 'ghost' character that lets any letter go there.

```
 import sys
#list of words that are available
list1 = [
"hello",
"saryt",
"artsy"
]

c = 0
#letters that can't be used
deadletters = ("h","e","l","l","o")

#sorts out words with dead letters
for word in list1:
if not any(map(lambda x: x in word, deadletters)):
 if "a"+""+""+""+"y" in word:
   #only lets words with "a___y" through
   print(f"found: {word}")
   c += 1
 
print(c)
sys.exit
```

Comment: Does this mean you want artsy to be found but not saryt?

Comment: Yes that is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [
    "hello",
    "saryt",
    "artsy",
    "ahoy"
]

#letters that can't be used
deadletters='hello'

#sorts out words with dead letters
list2 = [w for w in list1 if not(any(set(w) & set(deadletters)))]
print(list2)

#only lets words with "a___y" through
found = [w for w in list2 if (w[0] == 'a') & (w[-1] == 'y')]

print(found)
```

Comment: Wordle 232 3/6

⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
⬛⬛
